# Decomposing $y_n$ into $E(y_n|x_n)+\epsilon_n$. Under what condition is $\epsilon_n=o_p(1)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, linear-regression

Let $y_n,x_n$ denote two sequences of random variables. Define
$$
y_n=\operatorname{E}(y_n\ |\  x_n)+\epsilon_n
$$
Does $\operatorname{var}(y_n\  |\  x_n)=o_p(1)\implies \epsilon_n=o_p(1)$?

I tried to use the law of total variance. But then I need uniform integrability to prove the above. I am hoping there is another way which does not require stronger assumption.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & y = E(y|x)+\epsilon \\ \text{versus } & y = \operatorname E(y\mid x) + \varepsilon \\ {} \\ & var(y|x)=o_p(1) \\ \text{versus } & \operatorname{var}(y\mid x) = o_p(1) \end{align} $$ Which do you think looks better in each of these pairs?

Comment: You  sounded like my supervisor but okay.

Comment: I notice that you used `\text{var}` rather than `\operatorname{var}`. Are you aware that those do not always have identical effects? In particular, `\text` does not result in context-dependent spacing.

Comment: Can you explain the notation $o_p(1)$ ?

Comment: @Thomas $\operatorname{var}(y\  |\  x)=o_p(1)$ means $\operatorname{var}(y\  |\  x)\xrightarrow[]{p}0$.

Comment: So you mean that $var(y|x)$ tends in probability to $0$ ? but to say convergence we need a sequence of r.v., not just one. Could you clarify ? Maybe you want to say $y_n$ ?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited the notation.

Comment: Are (x_n,y_n) iid?

Comment: ( maybe you could add your total variance approach )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea. We can use Chebyshev inequality conditioned on $x_n$, reading:

$P({|y_n-E[y_n|x_n]|>\epsilon}|x_n)\le \frac{Var(y_n|x_n)}{\epsilon^2}$

Now take expecations w.r.t. $x_n$ (e.g. multiply by $p(x_n)$ and integrate):

$P({|y_n-E[y_n|x_n]|>\epsilon})\le \frac{E[Var(y_n|x_n])}{\epsilon^2}$

If we can justify that $E[Var(y_n|x_n)]\rightarrow 0$ for n large than we are done, even if maybe we need some more additional hypothesis to finish this way. You have an hypothses that $Var(y_n|x_n)$ goes to zero in probability but I am not sure this always also implies that the expected value goes to zero.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I believe uniform integrability will be needed for the second line. It would be interesting to know what other conditions can be used to replace uniform integrability.

Comment: Hi Chuck of course every line has its hypothesis also the first one. What do you mean by 'uniform integrability' ? Anyway as I wrote even when passing from first to second line we would still need from this approach to know that the expected value goes to zero in order to pass from second line to what we would like to show...

Comment: We want $p(x_n)$ in your notation to be uniform integrable. This is uniform integrability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability

Comment: Thanks for the definition! But from first to second line we are integrating on the whole range of x_n we are not bounding the integral on some finite set. Why should we need such an hypothesis ?

Comment: $Var(y_n|x_n)\xrightarrow[]{p}0$  plus uniform integrability implies $E[Var(y_n|x_n)]\rightarrow 0$ (convergence in mean). At the bottom of wiki, there is a section called "Relation to convergence of random variables".

Comment: Ah ok so you are indicating the passage from second equation to the conclusion, I had misunderstood... perfect I will check it

Comment: Anyway this uniform integrability is it really such a big assumption ? At the end for example if Var(yn|xn) is bounded with the same constant for every n , than I think you are going in that direction ... I think in most practical cases it should be a reasonable assumption no ?

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\operatorname{Var}(y|x)=\mathbb{E}((y-\mathbb{E}(y|x))^2|x)=\mathbb{E}(\epsilon^2|x)$$

Here $\epsilon$ is zero mean. Assume $\operatorname{Var}(y|x)=0$ with probability 1. Taking unconditional expectations and using the law of iterated expectations this implies $E(\epsilon^2)=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon)=0$. Hence $\epsilon=0$ with probability 1.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you take unconditional expectation to imply $\text{E}(\epsilon^2)=0$ since $\text{var}(y|x)$ is $o_p(1)$ but not 0.

Comment: @chuck To use the well-known result that if $Var(Z)=0$, then $P(Z=\mathbb{E}(Z))=1$

Comment: It seems you only proved that $\epsilon|x=o_p(1)$? To go from conditional to unconditional, I don't see how without uniform intergrability.

Comment: @chuck I use the law of iterated expectations there, I added that.

Comment: Thanks. But $\operatorname{var}(y|x)=o_p(1)$ so it only converges in probability to 0. Applying law of iterated expectations only works when $\operatorname{var}(y|x)=0$ right?

Comment: @chuck If $E(A|B)=0$ with probability 1 then $E(A)=0$.

Comment: I see. So you strengthen the assumption from $o_p(1)$ to $o_\text{almost surely}(1)$. This is not what I am looking for but it is still very helpful to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$E(y_n|x_n)$ is just a function of $x_n$ (we'll call it $\mu(x_n)$), and computing $\text {var}(\cdot|x_n)$ treats $x_n$ as a constant, so we can say

$\text {var}(y_n|x_n)=\text {var}(\mu(x_n)+\varepsilon_n|x_n)=\text {var}(\varepsilon_n|x_n)$,

so $\text {var}(y_n|x_n)=o_p(1)\iff \text {var}(\varepsilon_n|x_n)=o_p(1)$.

Not sure we can say $\varepsilon_n=o_p(1)$  but we can say it has mean zero:

$E[y_n]=E[\mu(x_n)]+E[\varepsilon_n]\underbrace{=}_{\text {law of iter. exp.} }E[y_n]+E[\varepsilon_n]\implies E[\varepsilon_n]=0$ .

Comment: I dont agree with the last part where you show $\epsilon_n$ is $o_p(1)$ since its not an average quantity.

Comment: @chuck, thanks-edited